# Specify the element when multiple elements matching

Tags: rspec, capybara

How can I with capybara select an item using `within`?

I have the following HTML

```
<div id ="projects"> 
  ...
  <div class="card">lorem</div>
  <div class="card">ipsum</div>
</div>
```

And I need to select the second div with `class='card'`.

```
  within(:css, '#attachments') do
    within(:css, '.card') do
     expect(page).to have_text('ipsum')
    end
  end
```

But not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
within all(:css, ".card")[1] do
  expect(page).to have_text('ipsum')
end
```

By the way, if you haven't set a different `default_selector` in your `spec_helper.rb`, like

```
Capybara.default_selector = :xpath
```

you can just use

```
within all(".card")[1] do
 expect(page).to have_text('ipsum')
end
```

since by default Capybara will use `:css` as `default_selector`.

Comment: Capybara indexing does not start at 1.  If you were writing custom XPath that has indexing that starts at 1 (by the definition of the XPath language) but in this case you're indexing into the results object which behaves like a ruby array so indexing starts at 0.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing `within(page.find_all(:css, '.card')[0]) do ...` but your code is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Sig If you need the first element then you should be using `first(...)` rather than `find_all(...)[0]` - or use a specific XPath selector as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to select that element that would depend on what exactly the `...` document structure before the two divs is (are there other divs, etc).  One method that wouldn't depend on that structure is shown in the answer by @fabersky, which is to use `all` and index into the results (`all('.card')[1]`) - and if the page is highly dynamic you might want to specify a minimum on that like (`all('.card', minimum: 2)[1]`).  Another option would be to write an XPath to match only the correct element (it's generally better practice to prefer selectors that return a single element over using `all` and indexing into the results whenever possible).

```
within(:css, '#attachments') do
  within(:xpath, XPath.css('.card')[2]) do
    expect(page).to have_text('ipsum')
  end
end
```

In this case the `[2]` is part of the XPath expression (which becomes `.//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' card ')][2]`) so the indexing does start at 1